# What's the alternate naming convestion for part fields

Tags: orchardcms

What is the file name I should give in my Orchard CMS theme to override the title of a blog post summary.

Conditions

- my alternate shape should apply only to blog post
- only to the title of the blog post
- only when the blog post is displayed in summary

Sadly going through the documentation [this](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates) I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

Parts.Title.Summary-BlogPost.cshtml

Could also do it by creating a folder called "Parts" in your theme directory and using Title.Summary-BlogPost.cshtml